# ruby open3 stdout and stdin how to interact

Tags: ruby, popen3

`sum.rb` is very simple. You input two numbers and it returns the sum.

```
# sum.rb
puts "Enter number A"
a = gets.chomp
puts "Enter number B"
b = gets.chomp
puts "sum is #{a.to_i + b.to_i}"
```

`robot.rb` used `Open3.popen3` to interact with `sum.rb`. Here's the code:

```
# robot.rb
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('ruby sum.rb') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr| 
  while line = stdout.gets
    if line == "Enter number A\n"
      stdin.write("10\n")
    elsif line == "Enter number B\n"
      stdin.write("30\n")
    else
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```

`robot.rb` failed to run. Seems it's stuck at `sum.rb`'s `gets.chomp`.

Later I found out I have to write as following to make it work. You need to feed it with inputs before hand and in right sequence.

```
# robot_2.rb
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('ruby sum.rb') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr| 
  stdin.write("10\n")
  stdin.write("30\n")
  puts stdout.read
end
```

What confused me are:

1. `robot_2.rb` is not like **interact with shell**, it's more like **feed what the shell needs, cause I just know**. What if a program needs many inputs and we cannot predict the order?
2. I found out if `STDOUT.flush` been added after each `puts` in `sum.rb`, `robot.rb` could run. But in reality we cannot trust `sum.rb`'s author could add `STDOUT.flush`, right?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out how to do this. Use `write_nonblock` and `readpartial`. The thing you have to be cautious of is that `stdout.readpartial` does exactly what it says, meaning you're going to have to aggregate the data and perform the `gets` yourself by looking for newlines.

```rb
require 'open3'
env = {"FOO"=>"BAR", "BAZ"=>nil}
options = {}
Open3.popen3(env, "cat", **options) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
    stdin.write_nonblock("hello")

    puts stdout.readpartial(4096)
    # the magic 4096 is just a size of memory from this example:
    # https://apidock.com/ruby/IO/readpartial


    stdin.close
    stdout.close
    stderr.close
    wait_thr.join
}
```

For people who are looking for more generic interactivity (for example ssh interactions), you probably want to create separate threads for aggregating the stdout and triggering stdin.

```
require 'open3'
env = {"FOO"=>"BAR", "BAZ"=>nil}
options = {}
unprocessed_output = ""
Open3.popen3(env, "cat", **options) {|stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|

    on_newline = ->(new_line) do
        puts "process said: #{new_line}"
        # close after a particular line
        stdin.close
        stdout.close
        stderr.close
    end

    Thread.new do
        while not stdout.closed? # FYI this check is probably close to useless/bad
            unprocessed_output += stdout.readpartial(4096)
            if unprocessed_output =~ /(.+)\n/
                # extract the line
                new_line = $1
                # remove the line from unprocessed_output
                unprocessed_output.sub!(/(.+)\n/,"")
                # run the on_newline
                on_newline[new_line]
            end

            # in theres no newline, this process will hang forever
            # (e.g. probably want to add a timeout)
        end
    end

    stdin.write_nonblock("hello\n")

    wait_thr.join
}
```

BTW this is not very threadsafe. This is just an unoptimized but functional solution I've found that will hopefully be improved in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I played with @jeff-hykin's answer a bit. So, the main bit is to send the data from `sum.rb` in nonblocking mode, i.e. use `STDOUT.write_nonblock`:

```
# sum.rb
STDOUT.write_nonblock "Enter number A\n"
a = gets.chomp
STDOUT.write_nonblock "Enter number B\n"
b = gets.chomp
STDOUT.write_nonblock "sum is #{a.to_i + b.to_i}"
```

-- notice the `\n` in the `STDOUT.write_nonblock` calls. It separates the strings/lines, that are read with `gets` "get string" in `robot.rb`. Then `robot.rb` can stay the same. I would only add `strip` in the conditions:

```
# robot.rb
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('ruby sum.rb') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  while line = stdout.gets
    puts "line: #{line}" # for debugging
    if line.strip == "Enter number A"
      stdin.write("10\n")
    elsif line.strip == "Enter number B"
      stdin.write("30\n")
    else
      puts line
    end
  end
end
```

My Ruby version is 3.0.2.